# i can't get the value from an input

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

i'm making a basic timer, is one of my first projects, when you press a button the code should create 3 different variables that obtain the values from their respective inputs, this 3 symbolize hours, minutes and seconds.

what happens is that if you console.log any of this 3 variables you get that is undefined for some reason, if you don't have this values the entire countdown will not work.

the inputs are set to start at value = 0 in the html, so it's supposed to at least return 0, not undefined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="title-container">

    <div class="title"><h1>vamos a meditar un poco...</h1> </div>

</div>

<div class="timer-container">
    <div class="screen-timer"><h2></h2></div>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="60" value="0" id="hours">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="60" value="0" id="minutes">
    <input type="number" min="0" max="60" value="0" id="seconds">
</div>    

<div class="button-container">
    <button class="btn">Iniciar</button>
</div>


<script src="app.js"></script>
```

here is the javascript code:

```
   let button = document.querySelector(".btn");
let title = document.querySelector(".title");
let screenTimer = document.querySelector(".screen-timer");

//quotes
let quotes = ["OM MANI PADME HUM", "OM", "BUENOS PENSAMIENTOS, BUENAS PALABRAS, BUENAS ACCIONES", "YO FLUYO COMO EL AGUA"];

//timer start button
button.addEventListener("click", function(){

//time units
let h = document.getElementById("hours").value;
let m = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
let s = document.getElementById("seconds").value;


//title changer
let index = parseInt((Math.random() * quotes.length));
title.innerHTML = `<div class="title"><h1>${quotes[index]}</h1></div>`;

//interval for the timer
let intervalId = setInterval(timer, 1000);

//timer
function timer(){

    if(m > 0 && s <= 59){
        s--;
    } else if(m > 0 && s == 0){
        m--;
        s = 59;
    } else if (h > 0 && m == 0 && s == 0){
        h--;
        m = 59;
        s = 59;
    }

    if (h === 0 && m === 0 && s === 0){
        clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
}


//show the timer on the screen
screenTimer.innerHTML = `<div class="screen-timer"><h2> ${h + ":" + m + ":" + s} </h2></div>`


console.log(h);
console.log(m);
console.log(s);
console.log(h.value);
console.log(m.value);
console.log(s.value);
});
```

*i saw other solutions where people write document.getElementById(id).onClick instead of using addEventListener("click", ...) for making the button work when its clicked on, but i think it's the same*

Comment: you're already getting the value in `h`, `m`, and `s` because you are using `let h = document.getElementById( "hours" ).value;`.

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the values for hours, minutes, and seconds correctly here,

```
let h = document.getElementById("hours").value;
let m = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
let s = document.getElementById("seconds").value;
```

And they are giving correct results in your console logs as well,

```
console.log(h);
console.log(m);
console.log(s);
```

What you are doing wrong is then trying to access the .value property of these three variables which doesn't exist and that is why `undefined` is getting printed.

Use **h, m, s** variables for your output.

Answer (score 0):

The first three console.logs yield the correct results.

```
console.log(h);
console.log(m);
console.log(s);
```

These are already the values themselves not the domnodes.

```
console.log(h.value);
console.log(m.value);
console.log(s.value);
```

When you try to access the property "value" on the values themselves the result is undefined.